# intel realsense tare calibration

Tags: c++, realsense

I'm trying to play with the depth calibration API rs2_run_tare_calibration , but unfortunately im getting back NULL result as the new calibration table. I'm wondering if there is special step im missing. basically I'm starting an asyc thread which runs the tare calibration and then set the result to a future. I have upgraded the camera firmware and SDK to latest

```
std::future<const rs2_raw_data_buffer*> RealSenseDevice::startCalibration(const float ground_truth_mm, const void *jsonContent,int contentSize,rs2_update_progress_callback_ptr progressCallback, const int timeout) {
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async,[this,ground_truth_mm,jsonContent,contentSize,progressCallback,timeout]()->const rs2_raw_data_buffer*{
        rs2_error* e = nullptr;
        auto calibrationTable = rs2_run_tare_calibration(device.get().get(),20000,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,timeout*10,&e);
        if(calibrationTable!= nullptr){
            Log::Debug("SUCCESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!") << Log::Endl;
        } else
            Log::Debug("FAILEDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!") << Log::Endl;
        return calibrationTable;
    });
    return future;
}
```

Comment: did you try checking the value of `e`?

Comment: it's coming back as null as well